# How do I merge columns that have similar names in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has the words Due Date written differently but it all means the same. The problem is in my master data(xls file), one due date has an extra space or doesnt and i cant change that.All i can change is my final output.

```
Sr no Due Date    Due Date   DueDate
1     1/2/22      
2                  1/5/22    
3
4                         
5                             ASAP
```

I just want that column 2 and 3 all combine under column one at the same location they were

```
Sr No.  Due Date
1        1/2/22
2        1/5/22
3        
4
5        ASAP
```

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of the dataframe's structure with `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`?

Comment: Your columns have the same names `Due Date`?

Comment: @Corralien no there are different column names. But due date shows up multiple times spelt wrong. in some column name there is an extra space in front of ' Due Date' or 'Due Date   '.   so pandas doesnt automatically bring it under one column 'Due Date'

Comment: Do you have a common string between this columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` with a regex to get similar names, then `bfill` and get the first. Finally join to original devoid of the found columns:

```
d = df.filter(regex=r'(?i)due\s*date')
df2 = (df
 .drop(columns=list(d.columns))
 .join(d.bfill(1).iloc[:,0])
 )
```

Output:

```
   Sr no Due Date
0      1   1/2/22
1      2   1/5/22
2      3     None
3      4     None
4      5     ASAP
```

Comment: This worked thank you so much. I just discovered though that one of the 'due date' was also spelt 'duee date'. any solution for that within this?

Comment: You can try `r'(?i)due.*date'`

Comment: worked too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with `bfill`

```
out = df.bfill(axis = 1)[['Sr No','Due Date']]
```

Comment: Hi Beny, thanks for your answer. however, it only outputs 2 columns and i have more. Is there anyway to do this without mentioning 'Sr No' and it just aligning based on index or row number?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# set test data
data = {"Sr no": [1,2,3,4,5],
        "Due Date": ["1/2/22", "", "", "", ""], 
        "Due Date ": ["", "1/2/22", "", "", ""],
        " Due Date": ["", "", "", "", "ASAP"]
       }

# create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

```
# clean up column names 
df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns]

# group data
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: ''.join([str(l) for l in y if str(l) != "nan"]), axis=1))

# reorder column
df = df[['Sr no', 'Due Date']]

df
```

Returns

[image]